# read csv file with json as string in csv and convert to json apache spark scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I have a csv file like this:

```
id|jsonData
1|"[{""phone"":1989731788,""sources"":[""ecventa/clientecompania""],""lastDate"":1227532475000},{""phone"":374660,""sources"":[""ecventa/clientecompania""],""lastDate"":1227532475000}]"
```

and then I have a StructType like this:

```
val nestedPhone = new StryctType()
                      .add("phone",StringType,true)
                      .add("sources",ArrayType(StringType),true)
                      .add("lastDate",StringType,true)
val myStructType = new StructType()
                       .add("id",StringType,true)
                       .add("formatedData",ArrayType(nestedPhone),true)


var batchDF    = spark.read.format("csv")
                           .option("header", "true")
                           .option("delimiter", "|")
                           .load("mycsvPath")
```

Can I create a new Dataframe with myStructType using batchDF?

I test with this:

```
val result = batchDF
             .withColumn("formatedData",from_json(expr("substring(jsonData, 2, length(jsonData) - 2)"),ArrayType(nestedPhone)))
```

but that works bad because FormatedDate return null row.

Answer (score -1):

try in this way

```
  val nestedPhone = new StructType()
  .add("phone", StringType, true)
  .add("sources", ArrayType(StringType), true)
  .add("lastDate", StringType, true)

 val batchDF = sparkSession.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter", "|")
  .load("src/main/resources/file.csv")

 val result = batchDF
  .withColumn("formatedData",
    from_json(
      expr(
        "substring(jsonData, 2, length(jsonData) - 2)"
      ), ArrayType(nestedPhone)
    )
  )
```

Comment: my problem isn't read csv file, my problem is to convert a string(jsonData) to array of Struct.

Comment: try removing the double quotes on the array fields,

like this: `id|jsonData
1|"[{"phone":1989731788,"sources":["ecventa/clientecompania"],"lastDate":1227532475000},{"phone":374660,"sources":["ecventa/clientecompania"],"lastDate":1227532475000}]`